# Not understanding why my symbol filter doesn't work in C# when I run a negative modifier

Tags: c#

I'm new to all of this and I'm working on an introductory project in C#. My program takes a message input and a modifier input to create an caesar cipher, then using the same modifier decrypts it.

In my loop in the Cypher method, I have a nested loop that filters out symbols, which works encrypting but it throws an error

> index was outside the bounds of the array

when decrypting, I'm not exactly sure why? Can anyone help? Thanks

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    // get user message input
    Console.Write("ENTER MESSAGE: ");
    string messageIn = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    // get modifier input and convert to int
    Console.Write("MODIFIER?: ");
    string modIn = Console.ReadLine();

    int mod = Int32.Parse(modIn);

    // convert message to an array of chars
    char[] secretMessage = messageIn.ToCharArray();

    // generate encryption and print
    char[] encrypt = Crypt(secretMessage, mod);
    string encryption = String.Join("", encrypt);
    Console.WriteLine($"Encryption: {encryption}");

    // generate decryption and print
    char[] decrypt = Crypt(encrypt, -mod);
    string decryption = String.Join("", decrypt);
    Console.WriteLine($"Decryption: {decryption}");
}

static char[] Crypt(char[] input, int modi) 
{ 
    // vars
    char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char[] symbs = {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', ' '};

    // make new empty array set to last arrays length
    char[] cryptMesssageArray = new char[input.Length];

    // for loop that loops through all cryptMessage chars
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) 
    {
        bool flag = false;

        // looping through symb to exclude them
        foreach (char symb in symbs) 
        {
            // checking if it uses a symb
            if (input[i] == symb) 
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    
        if (flag == true) 
        {
            continue;
        }

        // vars
        char secretChar = input[i];
        int alphChar = (Array.IndexOf(alphabet, secretChar) + modi) % 26;
        char cryptChar = alphabet[alphChar];

        // add char to cryptMesssage
        cryptMesssageArray[i] = cryptChar;
    }

    // return array
    return cryptMesssageArray;
}
```

I input "`hello!`" to the first `Console.ReadLine();`, and `3` into the second.

I expect

```
Encryption: khoor
Decryption: hello
```

to be the output

But this is what I get instead:

```
Encryption: khoor
```

> Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn about debugging. Do you know what line of code throws the exception? What is the value of index? Also, learn about minimal reproduceable example. You test doesn't use symbols. Does the problem happen without that part of the code If it does - remove it before posting on SO...

Comment: By the way, `if (flag == true)` can be reduced to simply `if (flag)`. Your `flag` variable is already a Boolean. It also usually makes your code clearer if you use a useful name for things like flags, like `isSymbol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is little tricky, as I copied your code and it works seamlessly :)

But I can give you some guidelines:

This kind of exception means that you tried to access array's item with index, which is outside of array bounds - lower bound is 0 (first element) and upper bound is `item count - 1` which is index of last item.

So you have to focus on places, where you try to access array's item with index. In you code those places are:

```
cryptMesssageArray[i]
alphabet[alphChar]
input[i]
```

Now, `i` is loop variable, which changes in range `0 ... input.Length - 1` due to `for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)`.

So `i` variable is totally safe to access `input`, as it changes exactly within this array's boundaries, so `input[i]` is totally ok.

Now, `cryptMesssageArray[i]` is also ok, as you're instantiating the array with:

```
char[] cryptMesssageArray = new char[input.Length];
```

So it has exactly same boundaries as `input` array.

So the only candidate left is `alphabet[alphChar]`.

Indeed, the way you are calculating `alphChar` is "dangerous":

```
int alphChar = (Array.IndexOf(alphabet, secretChar) + modi) % 26;
```

Why it is dangerous? You are correctly "limiting" the value by taking mod: `% 26`, but 26 is hardcoded length of `alphabet`, which is reasonable approach, BUT if you change `alphabet` array (remove an item), it can give you the error.

In order to correct that, you should use `alphabet.Length` instead of hardcoded 26:

```
int alphChar = (Array.IndexOf(alphabet, secretChar) + modi) % alphabet.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

`modi` could be negative. Final result of modulo operation would also be negative. Add the modulus (26) to the operand to fix this (or in line with the other answer add `alphabet.Length`):

int alphChar = (Array.IndexOf(alphabet, secretChar) + 26 + modi) % 26;

BTW, instead of waiting for the answer from other people it is better to debug the code and see the problem for yourself. It's also faster.